# Adding class to id in Safari only

Tags: javascript

I am noob when it comes to **js** and appreciate the advice.

I am trying to target Safari only and add a class to an id... but it's not working. 
Please see below.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
  document.getElementById('menu-main-menu').className += ' menu-main-menu-safari';
}
```

Comment: Could you share the reason why you need to specifically target Safari? Are you 100% sure it's not a problem that can be fixed in next releases  leaving your website broken in future versions of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Want a proof?

On Safari right-click on "Questions" orange button in **this web page of S.O.** and "Inspect Element"

Then paste the following code on the console:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    document.getElementById('nav-questions').className += ' menu-main-menu-safari';
}
```

It's exactly your code execpt I changed the id to the one of the orange "Questions" button.

You'll see in the browser inspector the class added to the button element.

So as the code is correct probably you have some issues with the css class properties (or it's just the element id wrong).

---

Side note: I had to deal with a couple of issues (bugs) with Safari and one in Chrome recently.

I understand the need for a browser-specific patch.

Just organize your code in order to remove easily the patches as the browsers get fixed. As the patches may be no more needed or -worse- cause misbehaviour.

Comment: So if any browser puts "Safari" in their user agent string and not "Chrome", this will "identify" it as Safari. Not particularly reliable, and why the user agent string should never be used for browser detection.

Comment: @Robg Your first sentence is right: but when I design a web page I put effort to accomplish that every -user despite of his/her (modern) web browser choice- will see the page as it should be. **Unless the user deliberately tampered with the user agent !**.

Comment: @RogB `the user agent string should never be used for browser detection` If it's for security reasons I agree. If the page appearance all rely on it I agree. I you just have to workaround a bug of a specific browser-version-os for a single element of the page (for me) is ok.

Comment: The user agent string is **entirely** implementation dependent, there are [*thousands of them*](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/All/). BTW, Arora, Cheshire, Comodo_Dragon, Epiphany  and many others will all be identified as "Safari" by looking for "Safari" but not "Chrome".

Answer (score -1):

You probably won't like this, but browser detection is **bad** and is the reason for the [user agent mess](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/). Instead you should use feature detection, perhaps with [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

Comment: Not my down vote, but I guess it's because this should be a comment, not an answer (but is good advice all the same).